# Android: How shall I create Bitmap image bast on byte array?

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I have a byte array that I want to save it as a bitmap image. what should I do? 
I saw android.graphics.Bitmap and found several methods but I don't know which one is suitable. 
createBitmap(int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config), for example. I have width and height but how can I give it my byte array?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the methods in the class [`BitmapFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html), e.g. [`public static Bitmap   decodeByteArray(byte[] data, int offset, int length)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29).

Offset should be 0 and the length should be `array.length` for you.

Comment: Thanks dear mreichelt. may be a stupid question, sorry, but i ask.  How it understand the width and height of my picture. actually, I had a picture then I extracted pixels and then manipulated pixels and know I want to save it with new name. this is my real problem.